# How Can i Find URLs in html by class, Make Links (php)

Tags: php

How can I extract this link from the html using class 'get-demo'

```html
<html>
.
.
.
.
<p class="get_demo"><a href="https://example.com/moile.apk" class="font-size-16 text-muted">text</a></p>
.
.
.
.
.
</html>
```

this is my code php to extract link from html

```php
 preg_match_all('~<a(.*?)href="([^"]+)"(.*?)>~', $text, $matches);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use PHP's [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) like this:

```
$my_html = '...
<p class="get_demo"><a href="https://example.com/moile.apk" class="font-size-16 text-muted">text</a></p>
...';

$all_p_tags = $page_dom->getElementsByTagName('p');

foreach ($all_p_tags as $p_tag) {
   if ($p_tag->getAttribute('class') === 'get_demo') {
       $all_a_tags = $p_tag->getElementsByTagName('a');

       foreach ($all_a_tags as $a_tag) {
           $links[] = $a_tag->getAttribute('href');
       }
   }
}

print_r($links);
```

Comment: If you paste the code into phpfiddle.org, it does work.  So, maybe your document html is different from the example you give--just debug and see what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex, 
`preg_match_all("/<a href=\"([^\"]+)\"[^>]*>([^<]*)<\/a>/", $text, $matches);`

You will get link $matches[1] .

Comment: how can i use <p class"get_demo">

Comment: @BENKHALDOUN If your all  tags are like this than try thi 
`preg_match_all('~"get_demo"><a(.*?)href="([^"]+)"(.*?)>~', $text, $matches);`

Comment: @BENKHALDOUN have you verified value of $matches?
print_r($matches).

Comment: He gave me this result
Array ([0] => Array () [1] => Array () [2] => Array () [3] => Array ())

Comment: Can you share me your html?

Comment: <p class="demo"><a href="https://example.com/Christmas.apk" download class="font-size-15 text-muted"
                             style="text-decoration: underline">Christmas.apk</a></p>

Comment: Note that you have now mentioned three different classes: demo, get_demo, and get-demo.  Perhaps your problem is that you're not looking for the right class.